# How to fix "Packfile is truncated" error when cloning Git repository with JGit

Tags: git, tags, git-clone, jgit

I'm trying to clone a Git repository using JGit APIs using Tag name and SSH protocol. While I am cloning facing "Packfile is truncated" error.

The repository has about 10 GB of data. The network was uninterrupted and fast.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

```
    CloneCommand command = Git.cloneRepository();
    command.setTransportConfigCallback(transport -> {
    SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
    sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(SSHSessionFactory);
    });
    command.setDirectory(new File("gitRootFolder"));
    command.setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList(gitBranchName));
    command.setBranch(gitTagName);
    command.setCloneSubmodules(true);
    Git git = command.call();
    git.close();
```